# Adding formatted table query to actual table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a way to alter my original table to the format I've created a query for.

This is my formatted table

```
select 
    MonthStandard
    , sum(case when Type = 'Gross Production' then Dollars end) as GrossProduction
    , sum(case when Type = 'Adjustments' then Dollars end) as Adjustments
    , sum(case when Type = 'Write-Offs' then Dollars end) as WriteOffs
    , sum(case when Type = 'Adjusted Production' then Dollars end) as AdjustedProduction
from [Portfolio Project].dbo.AdjustedProductionByMonth
group by MonthStandard
```

My original table named AdjustedProductionByMonth does not look like this but after I run this query it looks how I'd like for it to look. How can I add this to my original table and change the format.

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: You don't, the whole point of a database is to store the base, raw data, and then you transform that into the format you want to display when you wish to display it. You don't try and store the data-preformatted as that is a waste of space and will cause issues when you want to change the formatting.

Comment: I appreciate that thank you! My only reason for wanting to do this is so I can calculate the Year over Year of a specific month in my newly formatted table.  But perhaps a view will allow me to use the formatted table into the formula.

Comment: Add another column `sum(case when .... ) / lag(sum(case when ... ), 12) over (order by MonthStandard)`. Another level of subquery or CTE would help avoid repetition. Don't store this in a table, just use write it in a query.